# Laravel Blade Conditional @extend Statement Including Variable(s)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Apparently one can only use a ternary statement when implementing conditional logic with the `@extends` blade directive, ex)

```
@extends($test ? 'layouts.test' : 'layouts.default')
```

If one needs to pass a variable into the extended layout, such as with the following syntax:

```
@extends('layouts.test', ['variable' => true])
```

Is there any way to incorporate the variable passing syntax into the ternary statement?

---

**Edit:**

To add clarity, the logic I'm trying to accomplish with the ternary `@extends` call is as follows:

```
@if($test)
  @extends('layouts.test', ['variable' => true])
@else
  @extends('layouts.default')
@endif
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be done in the controller instead?

Comment: @kjones Yes you use ternary statement in `@extend` section in blade file

Comment: @linktoahref yes, most likely should be done in the controller but I am interested if it's possible this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will help you.

```
@extends($test ? ('layouts.test' ? ['variable' => true] : ['variable' => false]) : ('layouts.default' ? ['variable' => false] : ['variable' => true]))
```